# Can't get rid of default filter on Photoshop CS5 shapes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5

Everytime I create a new shape in Photoshop CS5, whether on a new layer, document, whatever, it's always starting out with a drop shadow. I can't figure out why this default filter is being applied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if you have a Style set on your Shape tool settings?

[image: Shape tool Style choices]

It should be set on the white rectangle with a red stipe over it, and it seems to remember this setting even if you close the document, and create a new one.